# Removing line numbers and tabs from txt file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When I import in the txt file I'm getting these results show below. I need to strip the lineNumber and \t from each value.

Basically, I need everything to the right of \t to append to a list and I need it to ignore the rest. This is what my code produces.

```
data = []
df = pd.read_csv("tIncomes.txt")
df.head(20)

    taxIncomes
0   1\t5601
1   2\t4977
2   3\t5959
3   4\t6267
4   5\t5221
5   6\t3094
6   7\t308
7   8\t458
8   9\t390
9   10\t74
10  11\t589
11  12\t290
```

After I've gotten rid of the 1\t, I need to extract the first digit of each value in the array and store it. So x = [5,4,5,6,5,3,3,...etc]

Comment: Is that exactly how the csv is formatted?

Answer (score 0):

The default delimiter pandas' read_csv method use is ',' (comma). It seems your data uses '\t' instead. According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can use the **sep** argument to guide read_csv otherwise.

Please try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("tIncomes.txt", sep='\t')
digits = [int(str(num)[0]) for num in data.iloc[:, 1] if num]
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my answer according to you question modification. If you find my answer suitable, I'll appreciate if you mark it as the one which resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to extract the value you need
such as:

```
data = []
df = pd.read_csv("tIncomes.txt")

data=[_.split('\t')[1][0] for _  in  df[" taxIncomes"]]
```

This is a method that does not require you to change the original code.